# Module not found exception after Gradle 7.3 and JDK 17 upgrade

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, upgrade, java-17

I was trying to upgrade Java multi-module project to OpenJDK 17, which forced me to upgrade Gradle version from 6.8 to 7.3. After making the changes in build.gradle file, now the build is successful. But when I start the application I am getting the following exception.

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module "foo" not found, required by "goo".

Also the module not found exception are throwing for the JARs which are not added in module path.

- The jars are copied to libs folder and added the following command in build.gralde

  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

Comment: Could you able to solve I too facing the same. ?